# Изменение SeekBar и вывод в textview времени

Tags: java, android

Перемотка  сеекбар работает,т.е дотрагиваюсь до сеекбар и перемещаю в нужную позицию и соотв. звук перематывается,но почему-то нет обновления сеекбара каждую секунду,хотя хендлер повесил

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        fab();
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
//нахожу в xml
        seekBar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sbar);
        playerText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textPlayer);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.clickbutton);
        potehanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.potehkianim);

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

//присваиваю обработчик плееру
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mediaPlayer.start();



            }
        });
        //у меня есть массив мелодий и на каждый case своя мелодия по нажатию на который воспр. мелодия+анимация


        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            arr_imageA[i] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(fragments[i]);

            arr_imageA[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    v.startAnimation(potehanim);

                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.imageView1:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a1.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView2:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a2.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView3:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a3.class);
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            if (pageNumber == 1) {

                rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {

                    arr_imageB[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            stopAnimation();


                            switch (v.getId()) {

                                case R.id.b1: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);

                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
                                    break;
                                }

                                case R.id.b2:

                                {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);

                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b3: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b4: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b5: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                                    break;
                                }

                                case R.id.b6: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);
                                    break;
                                }


                                case R.id.b7: {
                                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);
                                    break;
                                }

                            }


                        }

                    });
                }


                return rootViewB;

            }


        }

        return rootView;
    }
//запуск активити с задержкой
    public void startActivity(final Context activityContext, final Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(activityContext, activityClass));
            }
        }, 200);
    }
```

//метод в котором запускаю плеер

```
private void playSample(int resid) {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            stopAnimation();

        } else {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                afd.close();


            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

    }
```